# javascript function for multiple actions

Tags: javascript

if i am using this JS Code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     function showHideDiv()
    {
        var divstyle = new String();
        divstyle = document.getElementById("elementId").style.visibility;
        if(divstyle.toLowerCase()=="visible" || divstyle == "")
        {
            document.getElementById("elementId").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("elementId").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
</script>
```

and then this for my HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="Action" id="action" onclick="return showHideDiv();">Menu</a>
    <div id="elementId" style="visibility:hidden">
     content here
     </div>
```

what would be the best way to have another div with another link that expands the div but not have multiple functions for it?

Comment: function showHideDiv(id) pass in the id as a parameter and use that instead of elementId

Comment: i did try this but wasnt sure it would work, how do i pass the id as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a function argument:

```
function showHideDiv(id)
{
    var element = document.getElementById(id),
    visibility = element.style.visibility.toLowerCase(),
    isVisible = visibility === "visible" || visibility === "";

    element.style.visibility = isVisible ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
}
```

Then in your HTML, you pass it like this:

```
onclick="showHideDiv('elementId');"
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/unofaj/1/)

Comment: is this correct for the HTML?

<a href="#" onclick="showHideDiv('one');">Menu</a>
    <div id="one" style="visibility:hidden">
     content here
     </div>

Comment: @charliejsford Yeah, I guess so. Why don't you try first?

Comment: onclick="showHideDiv('elementId');" on the elementId -  what does that need to be? something else or to actually say elementId?

Comment: @charliejsford Sorry, I left an old variable reference in there. Updated.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
function toggleDiv(showDiv) {
    var elm, divstyle, isHidden;
    elm = document.getElementById("elementId");
    divstyle = elm.style.visibility;
    isHidden = divstyle.toLowerCase() == "visible" || divstyle == "" ? false : true;
    elm.style.visibility = (showDiv === true || (isHidden && showDiv !== false) ? 'visible' : 'hidden')
}
```

Usage:

```
toggleDiv() // Toggles visibility to opposite of current state.
toggleDiv(true) // Always shows div.
toggleDiv(false) // Always hides div.
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d2jkq/